# AgileCentral:: Pyral: Throws error:: Multiple work spaces found with the same name. You must specify a work space with a unique name

Tags: python-3.x, pyral, agile-central-api

I have 3 work spaces in Agile Central(rally). i want to pull all the projects from the 2 work spaces out of these 3.

I am using pyral python package.

**Below is the code snippet:**

```
from pyral import Rally

return Rally(server='rally1.rallydev.com', apikey=decoded_key, workspace=['Test-WORKSPACE-1', 'Test-Workspace-2'], projectScopeDown=False,verify_ssl_cert=False)
```

The above code throws error.

```
pyral.context.RallyRESTAPIError: Multiple workspaces (3) found with the same name of '['Test-WORKSPACE-1', 'Test-Workspace-2']'.  You must specify a workspace with a unique name.
```

**My system account has read access on all the 3 work spaces and all the projects within these 3 works spaces.** 
Can i specify multiple workspaces when query rally API? Am i doing something wrong here. Thank you so much for all your help here in advance.